# Segmentation fault when storing constant into a register

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

This question is most likely extremely dumb, but after one hour of trying I could not understand what's wrong with this:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:

    mov eax, 1

segment .bss
    val resb 2
```

This was the simple program in `nasm` which is set register value with a constant. When I compile it to `nasm -f elf64` and then link with ld and then run I got `Segmentation fault`. Why? What's wrong with this? I didn't touch memory, just set a constant into a register.

Comment: you're missing the end of your program. it sets the eax to 1 and then what?

Comment: This is a good time to learn `gdb` ;)

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Great, just added `system_exit` call and now works. But why does it cause `Segmentation fault`? Just didn't exit... and so?

Comment: Without an exit it will continue to execute whatever is in memory after the `mov eax, 1`. Likely it will run into a page of memory that is not executable eventually causing a fault.

Comment: Assuming zero-fill, the instruction after `mov eax, 1` here is `add [rax],al` which isn't going to work.

Comment: Sounds reasonable...

Comment: *"and so?"* - losing control over instructions is the major security problem nowadays, and back in 8/16b era it was major cause of unexpected reset of computer, losing all the unsaved work. ... .... ... maybe that's why refactoring was not a term back then, we did it without the term, whenever we lost the source... :D